# Angular/ TypeScript - How to Type casting in HTML file?

Tags: angular, typescript, casting

I have a TypeScript interfaces:

```
export interface iA {
  name: string;
}
export interface iB {
  size: number;
}
export interface iX {
  id: number;
  data: iA | iB;
}
```

Then in one of my Angular component class I'm using interface iX:

```
// example.component.ts
class ExampleComplnent {
  public item: iX = {
    id: 1,
    data: { name: 'test' }
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- example.component.html -->
<div>{{ item.data.name }}</div>
```

This will throw an error: `Propery 'name' not exist on type 'iB'`.

I know that in a TypeScript file I can use casting like this:

```
const name = (item.data as iA).name;
```

But how can I make casting on the HTML side?

I also want to mention that in my code I'm validating that `item.data` is of type `iA`, not of type `iB`. So I'm sure it have the property 'name'.

Comment: Are your type definitions correct - *can* `item.data` either have a `name` *or* a `size`? If so, what *do* you want to do if the one you render doesn't have a `name`? Note that's not type casting exactly, it's a [type *assertion*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I've updating my question. Basically I'm validating the type in my code.

Comment: Please give a [mre]. If it's only exposed to the template through the iX interface, the error is correct.

Comment: My first guess would be to try item.data?.name because when it is the other type, then that property does not exist.

Comment: That is valid code (Elvis operator/optional chaining) was already available in Angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible. It depends on your implementation what the best solution is. You can use generics:

```
export interface iA {
  name: string;
}
export interface iB {
  size: number;
}
export interface iX<T extends (iA | iB)> {
  id: number;
  data: T;
}

export class ExampleComponent {
  item: iX<iA>;
}
```

---

You can use some method call from the template which asserts the type:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '{{ getIaData(item)?.name }}',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  item: iX;

  getIaData(ix: iX): iA | undefined {
    return this.isIa(ix.data) ? ix.data : void 0; 
  }

  isIa(data: iA | iB): data is iA {
    return !!(data as iA).name;
  }
}
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xd5hx8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

and I'm sure there are more. But like I said, it depends on where you get the `item` from and how and where it is defined

Comment: Be careful when using functions inside template bindings. The function will be called on every change detections cycle.

Comment: @Aboodz, thanks for that comment. Yes I know that problem that why I used the generics approach.

Comment: @Aboodz using functions is not a bad thing. It keeps your template clean, and small methods like these are just as quick as a normal field binding. You can check this by using a getter. You will see that this is called just as much, and is basically also a function. If the calculated value is only affected by `@Input` values or by events listeners binded in the template, you can also think about calculating it only in the `ngOnChanges` hook. This technique can come in handy if the function gets more complex. And as always, use `OnPush` to reduce the amount of change detection cycles

Comment: I agree... Personally, I would only feel safe using a function binding when using `OnPush`. Otherwise, it's a pure pipe.

Answer (score 10):

One more solution. I use this for row template

1. Create utility function

```js
export function castTo<T>(): (row) => T {
  return (row) => row as T
}
```

2. Call function in component

```js
$row = castTo<YourType>();
```

3. Use in template

```js
$row(row).properties
```

Comment: You sir are a life savior

Comment: this is not performant

Comment: @SalminSkenderovic why is not performant?
It`s just type cast function like $any()
https://angular.io/guide/template-expression-operators#the-any-type-cast-function

Comment: @klivladimir I'm not certain, but I assume the angular compiler strips the $any function call from your compiled code.  It merely says  'dont typecheck here'!, 
whereas this `castTo` solution would not compile away.  
Because of that, there would be a performance hit because the function in the template will be called repeatedly during change detection.

Comment: @EricPhillips
I can't find the previous issue, but I find something similar.
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45468#issuecomment-1082257368

Answer (score 5):

As @PoulKruijt mentioned, Angular doesn't provide a way to cast using `as` in the component's template. However, you can consider using `$any()`, which cast to any. It will suppress the error but it is not type-safe.
Refer to this:
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-any-type-cast-function

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. I'm glad to learn something new. Thanks.

Comment: Soo, this has been here since v5 and I've never heard of it :D That's amazing. Although I dislike using `to any`, it's still good to know if there is really no way around it. Btw the correct link is https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#disabling-type-checking-using-any

Comment: Seems the link provided is not pointing to `$any()`. Here is another one: [https://ngrefs.com/latest/templates/any-type-cast](https://ngrefs.com/latest/templates/any-type-cast)